# I can't find a way to simplify this boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

> xyz' + x'y + x'z

the answer from boolean expression calculator on the internet is

> x'z + yz'

I know the end

> x'z

same like the answer. but I can't find a way to simplify

> xyz' + x'y = yz'

Comment: Here's a hint. Don't try to show $xyz' + z'y = yz'$ in isolation, it is probably easier to work with the entire expression the whole way through. Relations such as $x+x'=1$ and $x+1=1$ are useful for this problem. You can use $x+x'=1$ to add in terms that can then factorise with other terms and cancel.

Comment: thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can only derive
$$xyz'+x'y=y(xz'+x')=y(xz'+x'(z+z'))=\\
=y((x+x')z'+x'z)=y(z'+x'z)=yz'+yx'z$$
But it's enough to get
$$xyz'+x'y+x'z=yz'+yx'z+x'z=yz'+(1+y)x'z=yz'+x'z$$

Comment: i recalculate as what you are doing, and it's correct. good job sir.